# why is char *s = (char*)tag.c_str(); is wrong when tag is a string

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char

I am trying out this code and I found that it is working fine. But is this the correct way to convert string to char*.

`char* s1= "hello"; string s1 = (char*)s2.c_str();`

what is the meaning of this line: storing addresses to internal storage of temporary string objects is wrong.

Comment: `char* s1= "hello";` is wrong as well. In C++ all literal string are really ***constant** arrays of characters* (including the string null terminator). You need a `const char*` (or `char const*` which is exactly the same).

Comment: Also, the `c` in [`c_str`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is for *constant*. The function returns a `const char*`.

Comment: Oh, and if you feel the need to use C-style casting in C++ (like you do with `(char*)s2.c_str()`) then you should take that as a sign you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Yep. One of the easiest ways to find the mystery bug in the code is to look for the overly broad cast.

Answer (score 0):

`string` has a copy constructor. To copy `s2` into a new `string` `s1`, do `string s1(s2);`

Comment: Or the simpler `string s1 = s2;` or perhaps even `auto s1 = s2;`